# The release cycle of Software Collections?

Tags: rhel6, software-collections

I'm looking for information regarding Software Collections 2

1. Is there a release date for version 2?
2. Will httpd24 also be part of version 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no roadmap for  SCL and the latest version is 1.2 . The upgrades and updates are on as needed basis by RedHat. The SCL packages are the responsibility of their respective publishers.  The httpd24 is up to date and ready to go now and for the foreseeable future.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/1/html/1.2_Release_Notes/index.html

You can watch HTTPD24 through the issue tracker.

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/httpd24/

Answer (score 1):

Software Collections 2 were released in June.  You can see a list of additions here:  http://developerblog.redhat.com/2015/04/23/software-collections-2-0-now-beta/

The entire list is here with dates:  https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl

httpd is part of RHSCL 2.

RHSCL has a 3 year lifecycle.